# Using JGit, "IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object .... is not a tree

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm trying to implement the [code](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowChangedFilesBetweenCommits.java) here two diff two git commits.

```
try {                                                                                      
    ObjectId head = repo.resolve(tipCommit); //String with commit hash                                              
    ObjectId base = repo.resolve(baseCommit); //String with commit hash                                              
    log.info("Resolved HEAD as " + head.toString() + ", and base as " + base.toString());  
    try {                                                                                  
        ObjectReader reader = repo.newObjectReader();                                      
        log.info(repo.getAllRefs());                                                       
        log.info(base);                                                                    
        CanonicalTreeParser oldTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();                       
        oldTreeIter.reset(reader, base);                                                   
        CanonicalTreeParser newTreeIter = new CanonicalTreeParser();                       
        newTreeIter.reset(reader, head);                                                   
        try {                                                                              
            Git git = new Git(repo);                                                       
            List<DiffEntry> diffs = git.diff()                                             
                    .setNewTree(newTreeIter)                                               
                    .setOldTree(oldTreeIter)                                               
                    .call();                                                               
            //List<File> changedFiles = filesFromDiffs(diffs, git);                        
            git.close();                                                                   
            log.info("Changed Files: \n" + changedFiles);                                  
            return changedFiles;                                                           
        } catch (Exception e) {                                                            
            log.error("Error while trying to diff commits: ", e);                          
            //close git?                                                                   
        }                                                                                  
        //Do we need to close the reader here?                                             
    } catch (Exception e) {                                                                
        log.error("Error setting up repository parsers: ", e);                             
    }
```

This results in the following output:

```
Resolved HEAD as AnyObjectId[6c6b900d0a2d2783a2bdcde62cde0e04ac72aea0], and base as AnyObjectId[d97d892bba40f3676628625af0ae175deaffe9f8]
[SymbolicRef[HEAD -> refs/heads/mainline=6c6b900d0a2d2783a2bdcde62cde0e04ac72aea0], Ref[refs/heads/mainline=6c6b900d0a2d2783a2bdcde62cde0e04ac72aea0], Ref[refs/remotes/matt-2016-08-19T20-43-26/mainline=6c6b900d0a2d2783a2bdcde62cde0e04ac72aea0], SymbolicRef[refs/remotes/origin/HEAD -> refs/remotes/origin/mainline=d97d892bba40f3676628625af0ae175deaffe9f8], Ref[refs/remotes/origin/mainline=d97d892bba40f3676628625af0ae175deaffe9f8]]
AnyObjectId[d97d892bba40f3676628625af0ae175deaffe9f8]
Error setting up repository parsers: 
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.IncorrectObjectTypeException: Object d97d892bba40f3676628625af0ae175deaffe9f8 is not a tree.
```

As far as I can tell, both the commits I'm trying to compare are in the repo. So I don't know why the base commit isn't recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to feed commit id's (base, head) to the tree parsers. The latter, however, expect tree id's to be passed to `reset()`.

If you carefully look at the code you mention, you will note that tree id's are resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`baseCommit` should be like:

`ObjectId baseCommit = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");`

After you pull the latest changes, `tipCommit` should look like this:

`ObjectId tipCommit = repository.resolve("HEAD^{tree}");`

Hope, this will solve your problem.